# How to detect and handle different EOL in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to process a CSV file that can either be generated with CF or LF as an EOL marker. When I try to read the file with

```
infile = File.open('my.csv','r')
while line = infile.gets
...
```

The entire 20MB file is read in as one line.

How can I detect and handle properly?

TIA

Comment: By "CF or LF" do you actually mean "CRFL (windows) or LF (*nix)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would slurp the file, normalize the input, and then feed it to CSV:

```
raw = File.open('my.csv','rb',&:read).gsub("\r\n","\n")
CSV.parse(raw) do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

The above uses `File.open` instead of `IO.read` due to [slow file reads on Windows Ruby](http://phrogz.net/slow-file-reads-on-windows-ruby-1.9).

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, use a regex.

```
> "how\r\nnow\nbrown\r\ncow\n".split /[\r\n]+/
=> ["how", "now", "brown", "cow"]
```

So, something like

```
infile.read.split(/[\r\n]+/).each do |line|
  . . .
end
```

Now, it turns out that the standard library CSV already understands mixed line endings, so you could just do:

```
CSV.parse(infile.read).each do |line|
  . . .
```

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand. How do I separate the records? How do I know where one record in the CSV stops and the next one begins?

Comment: The first example reads the whole file and then splits it on any kind of line boundary into an Array of one-line-each elements, then sets up the block to handle each line individually.

The second example relies on `CSV` to understand the disparate line endings. It creates an array of arrays, where each inner array is a single line, split by the commas. The `line` variable yielded to the block is the Array of elements on a single line.

Comment: `CSV` Will also handle quotes nicely, which can be very beneficial.